# Does [[:space:]] work for sed patterns on all Linux distros?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Using `[[:space:]]` looks a little non-elegant and, quite frankly, Microsoft-ish for `sed` match patters.  I was trying to extract "Last" out of "First Last" and either of the following worked:

```
echo "First Last" | sed s/First //
echo "First Last" | sed s/First\s//
```

What did work is

```
echo "First Last" | sed s/First[[:space:]]//
```

I was wondering:

1. Is there is a more minimalistic notation to match a whitespace in `sed`?
2. Does `[[:space:]]` work on all Linux distros?

Comment: "Microsoft-ish"? That's a classic [BRE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) character class, it's as POSIX as it gets.

Comment: i just find `\s` to be more minimalist

Comment: That's specific to [PCREs](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/pcre.htm), you won't find it anywhere else.

Comment: it works with Java, Perl and Python RegEx patterns.

Comment: Yeah, Java uses PCRE.

Comment: By the way, the problem with `echo "First Last" | sed s/First //` is that you are passing two arguments to sed. You need to quote the argument: `echo "First Last" | sed "s/First //"` or `echo "First Last" | sed s/First\ //`

Comment: Thanks, @rici.  If you yank the comment and make it an answer, I will upvote it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `[:space:]` should be recognized by all `sed` editions, it is part of [Basic Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) as defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).

The `\s` notation is from Perl Compatible Regular Extensions which are implemented in many programs (grep with `-P` for example) and languages (perl, php, java, javascript, python...). 
Neither one of these regex syntaxes has anything to do with Microsoft!

If you want PCRE syntax, why not use Perl? Both of these work:

```
echo "First Last" | perl -pe 's/First\s//'
echo "First Last" | perl -pe 's/First *//'
```

The `-p` flag means "print every line" after performing whatever script was passed with `-e` on it.

Answer (score 0):

BRE syntax is *non-elegant* where some other variations are *elegant* because BRE is designed to be easily *abstracted*. BRE is simply parsed - a programmer implementing his/her own BRE-based grammar *subset* need never worry if the match string `\s` is meant to indicate a `\`backslash followed by an `s` or the `[[:space:]]` character class - because the former is always true. It is for this very same reason that syntax expressions are those that are `\(`escaped`\)` as opposed to `(`literal chars`)`, and why `\`backslashes lose their special meaning within `[`char classes`]`.

If you think this explanation something of a stretch, please first consider how simply it is actually done...

```sh
dot_whole_words()(
    s=[:space:] b=[:blank:] w=_[:alnum:] z1=\\{0,1\\}
    sed "G;s/[$b]*\([$w]*[^$w$s][^$s]*\)$z1\([$w]*\)[$s]/.\2/g"
)
```

That little shell function will pick out only *whole words* from an input line and separate those found with one or more `.`dots on output.

```sh
echo 1 2 3 four five si.x se\$Ven eight 9nine\! |
dot_whole_words
```

---

```
.1.2.3.four.five...eight.
```

It does annoyingly drop all words that have even a single punctuation point attached, as is evinced by *`9nine!`* failing to come across. This can also be handled with some additional abstraction.

```sh
whole_words_imp()(
        s=[:space:] b=[:blank:] w=_[:alnum:] p=[:punct:]
        z1=\\{0,1\\} p1=\\{1,\\} pn=[$p]$z1
        cs=\\\([$w]* ce=\\\)
        wd=$cs$ce    ce=$ce$z1
        nwd=$cs[$p][^$s]$p1$ce
        nwd=$nwd$cs[^$w$s$p][^$s]*$ce
        sed -ne:n -e'$!{N;/\n$/!bn' -e\} -eG \
                  -e"s/[$b]*$pn$nwd$wd$pn\([$s]\)$p1/\3\4/g" \
                  -e"/[^$s]/s/[$s]$p1/ /gp"
)
```

Now that version will read input a paragraph at a time, and, when it has found a blank line, it will reduce all of the input read so far to only *words* as might be composed of any number of *`[$w]`* chars, and which might be lead or trailed by at most one punctuation mark on either end.

For example:

```sh
printf %s\\n 1 2 3 \
       four five   \
       si.x se\$Ven\
       eight 9nine\! |
whole_words_imp
```

---

```
1 2 3 four five eight 9nine
```

And so, as I hope you can see, BRE is only as *elegant* as you make it to be.